# How to set Git configuration variable in Heroku without Git config file?

Tags: git, heroku

Simple question, I want ot set `receive.denyCurrentBranch` configuration variable to 'ignore'.
I rollbacked two commits on my master branch and added a new commit. When I tried to push to heroku I get this error message:

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
```

I am unable to set the configuration variable by means of `heroku config:set` or `heroku run git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore`. I get this message:

```
error: could not lock config file .git/config: No such file or directory
```

How can I set this?

Comment: have you tried accessing it at the console?

Comment: Are you sure you're pushing to the correct remote? To list all your remotes do: git remote -v

Comment: That error message means that you are outside of a git repo (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35674215/6309). Is it possible for heroku to set a git *global* config?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't specifically answer your question, but you should be able to re-deploy to Heroku by force pushing it.

```
git push -f heroku master
```