# How to set a Git config option when its config file is "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config"?

Tags: git, config

With Git, version 1.9.3 on Fedora Linux, version 20, I am querying for example the user's name like so:

```
git config user.name
# Foo Bar
```

But when I try to change it like so:

```
git config user.name 'Bar Foo'
```

I get the following error:

```
# error: could not lock config file .git/config: No such file or directory
```

In accordance to the "XDG Base Directory Specification" (http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) and the "FILES" section of the git-config(1) manpage I placed my Git config file under `"$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config"`.

Please note that the `"XDG_CONFIG_HOME` variable is set to `"$HOME/.config"` and the `GIT_CONFIG` variable is unset in my environment.

I am aware that the "FILES" section of the git-config(1) manpage states: "If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not set or empty, $HOME/.config/git/config will be used."

But then Git should ignore the `"$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config"` file  consistently, i.e.   while reading *and* writing.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You want `git config --global ...`, otherwise you'll set the configuration of the *current repo*, and by the looks of the error you're not in a repo when you run your command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to set it locally (in `.git/config`) rather than globally (in the XDG config in your home directory).

The error occurs because you're not actually in a repository.  It's a bit of a bogus error message but I can repeat it:

```
$ cd /someplace/with/no/repo; git config user.name boo
error: could not lock config file .git/config: No such file or directory
```

As [Biffen already mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193533/how-to-set-a-git-config-option-when-its-config-file-is-xdg-config-home-git-con#comment37350356_24193533), you need to add `--global`.

As [VonC notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674215/1256452), the misleading error message is changed to something sensible as of git version 2.8.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, if you forget `--global`, the error message will be more explicit with git 2.8 (March 2016).

See [commit 638fa62](https://github.com/git/git/commit/638fa623d5b5fb392a062edf61ccf086d35ab26b) (24 Feb 2016) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d3faba8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3faba840e758e6b5340b59a69e919fec77ce1c3), 26 Feb 2016)</sup>

> ## `git config`: report when trying to modify a non-existing repo config
>
> It is a pilot error to call `git config section.key value` outside of
>   any Git worktree.
>   The message

```
error: could not lock config file .git/config: No such file or directory
```

> is not very helpful in that situation, though. Let's print a helpful
>   message instead.

So at least now, you know when a `git config` is done *outside* a repo.