# error: could not lock config file .git/config: No such file or directory

Tags: git, heroku, visual-studio-code

Displays the following error:

heroku git:remote -a intense-journey-57915
Error: Command failed: git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/intense-journey-57915.git
error: could not lock config file .git/config: No such file or directory
fatal: could not set 'remote.heroku.url' to 'https://git.heroku.com/intense-journey-57915.git'

Actually this does exist. System variable HOME set correctly. Working in VS Code (as admin). Windows 10. Git version 2.23.0
Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actually this does exist.

Make sure you are in the right folder, meaning in your local Git repository.
Type simple `git config -l` for instance: [since Git 2.8 (March 2018), it will say if it is executed outside a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674215/6309).

The second test is to:

- close all your programs
- retry the git remote command in command line

  ```
  git remote add heroku 'https://git.heroku.com/intense-journey-57915.git
  ```

Hopefully, any program which might have kept an handle to the `.git/config` file has been closed and released said handle, allowing the `git remote` command to complete successfully.

Comment: @ProstoTak What does `git remote -v` return? Would a `git remote add heroku 'https://git.heroku.com/intense-journey-57915.git` work in command-line?

Comment: Somehow, I fixed it. I tried many things. Not sure what exactly helped

Comment: @ProstoTak I suspect closing programs helped: a handle to that file was released, allowing Git to work.